# How can I do this 'for each' code in SQL Server 2008 without using cursors?

Tags: sql-server-2008, cursor, set, spatial

I wish to do the following pseudo-code in SQL without the use of a `CURSOR`, if possible.

```
for each zipcode
{
    -- What city is this zipcode in? A zipcode can be in multiple cities, 
    -- but one city area is always way greater that the others.
    -- Eg. 90210 is 96% in the city of Beverly Hills. 
    -- The remaining 4% is that it s in some other fringe cties .. 
    --but only just (some mismatch mapping errors).

    ** grab the city largest shape area which this zip is a part of **
}
```

Now, I have some SQL to help us out.

```
-- All zipcodes and each boundary/shapefile.
SELECT ZipCodeId, Boundary FROM ZipCodes -- Boundary is a GEOGRAPHY field type.

To determine if a zipcode boundary is in a city....
SELECT CityId, CityName, 
    City.Boundary.Intersection(@someZipCodeBoundary).STArea() AS Area
FROM Cities
WHERE City.Boundary.Intersects(@someZipCodeBoundary) = 1
```

and to get the area of intersection (because we want the highest area of intersection ie. `TOP(1) ORDER BY Area DESC` or a `DISTINCT with an ORDER BY` sort of thing. We use the `Intersection` SQL method.

Note: `Intersects` and `Intersection` are two *different* Sql methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok - got it ;) The trick was to use a `PARTITION BY`. @In Sane gave me the idea when I realised I've done something similar, before :)

So .. here we go..

```
SELECT 
    a.CityId, a.Name, b.ZipCodeId, b.Code, a.Boundary.STIntersection(b.Boundary).STArea() AS Area, 
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY b.ZipCodeId ORDER BY a.Boundary.STIntersection(b.Boundary).STArea() DESC) AS Area_Rank
FROM 
    Cities a
    INNER JOIN ZipCodes b on a.Boundary.STIntersects(b.Boundary) = 1
    where b.Code = 12010 OR b.Code = 90210


CityId      Name                                                                                                 ZipCodeId   Code                 Area                   Area_Rank
----------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ----------- -------------------- ---------------------- --------------------
2166        Los Angeles                                                                                          9331        90210                13235413.8430175       1
1686        Beverly Hills                                                                                        9331        90210                10413397.1372613       2
2635        West Hollywood                                                                                       9331        90210                0                      3
14570       Amsterdam                                                                                            29779       12010                15369521.9602067       1
14921       Hagaman                                                                                              29779       12010                1394562.70390667       2
14856       Fort Johnson                                                                                         29779       12010                211058.884834718       3
14651       Broadalbin                                                                                           29779       12010                0                      4

(7 row(s) affected)
```

So in this filtered example (Filtered by ZipCode 12010 or 90210), we can see that this zipcode exists in 4 different cities/towns. Each zipcode can have 1 to many results, which are then ordered by the Area value .. but the key here is the `PARTITION` keyword .. which does this ordering by ZipCode groups or partitions. Very funky :) Notice how the zipcode 90210 has it's own rank results? same with 12010 ?

Next, we make that a subquery, and just grab all the Rank == 1 :)

```
SELECT CityId, Name, ZipCodeId, Code, Area_Rank
FROM (
SELECT 
    a.CityId, a.Name, b.ZipCodeId, b.Code, a.Boundary.STIntersection(b.Boundary).STArea() AS Area, 
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY b.ZipCodeId ORDER BY a.Boundary.STIntersection(b.Boundary).STArea() DESC) AS Area_Rank
FROM 
    Cities a
    INNER JOIN ZipCodes b on a.Boundary.STIntersects(b.Boundary) = 1
    where b.Code = 12010 OR b.Code = 90210
) subQuery
WHERE Area_Rank = 1


CityId      Name                                                                                                 ZipCodeId   Code                 Area_Rank
----------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ----------- -------------------- --------------------
14570       Amsterdam                                                                                            29779       12010                1
2166        Los Angeles                                                                                          9331        90210                1

(2 row(s) affected)
```

Sweet as candy :)

Side Note: This also shows me that my *Los Angeles* city shapefile/boundary is corrupted, because it's intersecting the zipcode 90210 far too much (which I visually confirmed :P)

[image]

Comment: the `WITH` keyword ... er ... that one I don't know :) Time to check this bad boy out ... Cheers for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

Does `Max` work for that?

Comment: Can you please elaborate? `MAX`?

Answer (score 0):

I must say that i have no idea about what Intersection / Intersects are or what they do and i must clarify that i dont understand this syntax below `Boundary.Intersection(@someZipCodeBoundary).` either

**Assuming that this query of yours returns all cities which intersect with the zipcodeBoundary specified and Area is their area of intersection**,

```
SELECT 
    CityId, 
    CityName, 
    City.Boundary.Intersection(@someZipCodeBoundary).STArea() AS Area 
FROM 
    Cities 
WHERE 
    City.Boundary.Intersects(@someZipCodeBoundary) = 1
```

Based on my understanding, what drachenstern is suggesting above is about using MAX is

```
SELECT 
    CityId, 
    MAX(City.Boundary.Intersection(@someZipCodeBoundary).STArea()) AS Area
FROM 
    Cities 
WHERE 
    City.Boundary.Intersects(@someZipCodeBoundary) = 1 
GROUP BY CityId
```

This should give you the CITYID which has the MAXIMUM intersection area.

Comment: Kewl ... but notice how in your sql example, i'm passing in a _SINGLE_ `@someZipCodeBoundary` ? This is what i'm trying to avoid :( With the above code ... i would have that in a cursor, right? I'm trying to avoid that.

Comment: @Pure.Krome - Yes, you are right. To that end, will the list of all zipcodes come from ZipCodes table? Also, does Cities table have Boundary field in it?

Answer (score -1):

Try another approach. Get somewhere a census statistics and filter out cities with maximum population grouped by the same zip code.

Like this [Gazetteer thing](http://www.census.gov/tiger/tms/gazetteer/zips.txt), for example.